# Many To Many associations with additional fields in Shopware 6

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

My database model looks like this:

One user can manage multiple companies (USER n:n COMPANY), let's say they are connected in the intermediate table USER_COMPANY and this table has one additional field 'active'.

I have created EntityDefinitions for both tables plus the MappingDefinition for the intermediate table:

COMPANY:

```
class CompanyDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    ...

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),

            ...

            new ManyToManyAssociationField(
                'users',
                UserDefinition::class,
                CompanyUserDefinition::class,
                'company_id',
                'user_id'
            ),
        ]);
    }
}
```

USER:

```
class UserDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{
    ....

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new IdField('id', 'id'))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            ...

            new ManyToManyAssociationField(
                'companies',
                CompanyDefinition::class,
                CompanyUserDefinition::class,
                'user_id',
                'company_id'
            ),
        ]);
    }

}
```

COMPANY_USER:

```
class CompanyUserDefinition extends EntityDefinition
{

    ...

    protected function defineFields(): FieldCollection
    {
        return new FieldCollection([
            (new FkField('company_id', 'companyId', CompanyDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            (new FkField('user_id', 'userId', UserDefinition::class))->addFlags(new PrimaryKey(), new Required()),
            (new BoolField('active', 'active'))->addFlags(new Required()),

            new ManyToOneAssociationField('user', 'user_id', UserDefinition::class, 'id'),
            new ManyToOneAssociationField('company', 'company_id', CompanyDefinition::class, 'id'),
        ]);
    }

}
```

Now I would like to do the filtering using the CompanyRepository. I would like to retrieve just companies that are connected to the logged user (I know their ID) while the connection needs to be active. Is there any way on how to do this? This doesn't work:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('users');
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('users.active', 1));

$companies = $this->companyRepository->search($criteria, $context);
```

It shows this error:

```
"class": "Shopware\\Core\\Framework\\DataAbstractionLayer\\Dbal\\Exception\\UnmappedFieldException",
"message": "Field \"active\" in entity \"user\" was not found.",
```

Comment: Did you find a solution meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, your CompanyUserDefinition has an "active" field, but your "UserDefinition" might not.

Comment: He wants to filter based on the column of the "in between" table, the mapping definition. This is not so weird since one can add extra fields. However I can't seem to find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround where we first create the entities with many to many relationship & afterwards use the repository for the mapping definition entity to update the row with the desired extra values.
Another solution could be replacing the many to many relation with one to many & many to one relationships with an in between table & treat the "in between" table as a separate entity.